# Golang exec: stat: no such file or directory after file has been moved there

Tags: deployment, go, stat, init.d

I have a script that I am using for deployment using the "os/exec" package. One of the commands that I use is as follows:

```
cpInit = exec.Command("cp", "initScripts/nginx", "/etc/init.d/nginx")
```

and another:

```
startNginx = exec.Command("/etc/init.d/nginx", "start")
```

Initially I ran the first command with `err := cpInit.Run()`, but later when I run the second command I get the error:

```
exec: "/etc/init.d/nginx": stat /etc/init.d/nginx: no such file or directory
```

But when the program exits `/etc/init.d/nginx` is there, so I thought maybe the first command didn't finished (even though `Run()` waits until the command returns). I changed `Run()` to `Start()` and `Wait()` only to get the same results. Can anyone tell me why the second command can't find that file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you run `exec.Command(...)` it immediately goes and checks for the file's existence, but has to defer the error until you call `Run()`, because the `Command()` call doesn't return an error.

See here for the definition of `Command`: http://golang.org/src/pkg/os/exec/exec.go?s=3410:3455#L99

It calls `LookPath(...)` defined here: http://golang.org/src/pkg/os/exec/lp_unix.go?s=902:944#L23

You need to initialize the `Command` after you know the file is there--after calling `Run()` on your copy command.